# VB How to make a click button run Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create in Visual Basic Studio a prompt for users who's password is about to expire. I would like to have a command button that runs Ctrl+Alt+Del to allow uses to change their password. This prompt will pop-up ever hour within 7 days of their password expiring. I have checked online but have been unable to find any solutions.

Comment: I seem to recall reading somewhere a long time ago that that specific keyboard combo was un-trappable and can't be faked. Windows 95 vintage comment. Not sure if it's still valid with USB keyboards and different kernel OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such way to send the Ctrl+Alt+Del keys to the system. From looking around I believe your only true option to get the Windows Password screen would be to have a message box or bubble appear on the users screen to remind them to press ctrl+alt+del to reset their password. The only other option is to make your own Password change box and utilize the UAC settings to change the password